# difference between custom css generator fluid css and fluid 960 grid system

Tags: css, 960.gs

so on 960:s homepage you can customize the grid and download the fluid version. so if i want a flexible grid this will do?

what's the thing about fluid 960 grid system? there are only 12 and 16 column versions. what if i have generated a 24 columns fluid version with 960 custom generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom CSS generator helps you use the same concept behind 960 but with other variables, and a fluid version as well. It was developed by Spry Soft and was *based* on 960.gs.

You can customize width, number of columns, and if you want a fluid layout using that generator. You might want to start with a simple site using just 960gs to get the hang of it before trying a 24 column fluid width layout.

Comment: are there any good tutorials taking up the other selectors like .suffix_x
.prefix_x
.push_x
.pull_x
.clear_fix? cant find any, and why dont they have a manual on their website for this. what is the point of releasing a product without manual to explain how to use and depend on various 3rd party tutorials that dont even take up everything?=/

Comment: @noname First, if you "View Source" on their demo page (http://960.gs/demo.html) you can see `suffix` and `prefix` in use as well as `clear`. `push` and `pull` should be combined with `position:relative` to move an element to the right (push) or to the left (pull) by a certain number of columns. Finally, 960 is not a product (which implies sale) but is a *free* open-source project which are characteristically under-documented. Sorry I don't have better news!

Comment: yes i understand that its an open source, but i just thought since there are just a few selectors it wouldnt take much time to just write a quick manual for which selectors are available and how to use them. would take just 1 min to read it through and understand. however, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [fluid24](http://www.fluid24.org/) it is a fluid 24 columns grid system based on [960.gs](http://960.gs/)